# bot.polling() issue with pytelegramapi

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I was just doing a simple lines of code and it gives a lot of issues just for using `bot.polling()`.

```py
import telebot

token = '19*******:********-********-lmY'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['greet'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")


bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First
`pip uninstall telebot`

Then
`pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`

```
import telebot

API_KEYS = "API TOKEN"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEYS)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['greet'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")

bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely happening because your environment variable for the API keys is unset:

```py
API_KEYS = os.getenv('API_KEYS')
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEYS)
```

If the environment variable for 'API_KEYS' is unset, `os.getenv` will return `None`. To fix this, make sure the environment variable is set correctly.

To identify this problem more easily in future, you should add key validation to provide a more meaningful error:

```py
try:
    API_KEYS = os.environ['API_KEYS']
except KeyError as error:
    raise ValueError("API keys are missing.") from err

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEYS)
```